# Unity Launcher send to back feature

Tags: launcher, window-manager, window, unity

Clicking on a running application's icon in the unity Launcher it brings the application to the front.

This is similar behavior to the old gnome taskbar except that in the old taskbar if I clicked a second time the window would be sent back to where it was in the front/back hierarchy.

Is this possible in unity?

---

> **Elaboration just to be clear:**
>
> I have four programs open
>
> - Firefox
> - Tasks
> - Thunderbird
> - Nautilus
>
> Firefox it topmost, below it is Tasks, and below that is Thunderbird
>   and at the bottom (or back) is Nautilus
>
> If I'm currently using Firefox and I want to quickly check on my Tasks
>   I can click the Tasks icon in the launcher and this window is brought
>   to the front.
>
> - Tasks
> - Firefox
> - Thunderbird
> - Nautilus
>
> However, having checked this I now want to go back to what I was doing
>   on Firefox. I used to be able to click the icon in the taskbar again
>   to achieve this.
>
> - Firefox
> - Tasks
> - Thunderbird
> - Nautilus
>
> This is not the case in unity. I have to move my mouse to the Firefox
>   icon in the launcher to go back to Firefox. Clicking the Tasks icon
>   again does nothing.
>
> **I'd like this old functionality duplicated in unity as it was a handy feature. Can anyone tell me if this is possible now or will be
>   in the future?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize window, by clicking again on it's launcher, it's called Dodge, and it was working in 11.10, but Canonical decide to [remove it](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/mark-shuttleworth-explains-dodge-ditch-decision-in-precise/). You can re-enable it by adding this ppa:
  1. Open terminal (from launcher, or shortcut: ctrl+alt+k)
  2. Execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped` (you have to enter your password in terminal after that.
  3. Execute `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
4. Log out and log in for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Awesome!! Works perfectly! Cheers :-D